# Scala Broadcast + UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to broadcast an List and pass the broadcast variable to UDF (Scala code is present in separate file). But facing issues.

```
val Lookup_BroadCast = SC.broadcast(lookup_data)
```

UDF creation with 3 arguments

```
val Call_Sub_Pgm = udf(foo(_: String, Lookup_BroadCast: org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[List[String]], Trace: String))
```

Calling the UDF using "withColumn"

```
Out_DF = Out_DF.withColumn("Col-1", Call_Sub_Pgm(col(Col-1),Lookup_BroadCast,lit(Trace)))
```

I am getting compilation error for above code - "found broadcast variable, required Sql Column"

If i remove "Lookup_BroadCast" variable from above

```
Out_DF = Out_DF.withColumn("Col-1", Call_Sub_Pgm(col(Col-1),Lookup_BroadCast,lit(Trace)))
```

then I get below error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.spark.masking.ExtractData$$anonfun$7 cannot be cast to scala.Function0
```

Answer (score 2):

Serializable wrapper class can be created for function, with Broadcast in constructor:

```
class Wrapper(Lookup_BroadCast: Broadcast[List[String]]) extends Serializable {
  def foo(v: String, s: String): String = {
      // usage example
    Lookup_BroadCast.value.head
  }
}
```

And used like:

```
val wrapper = new Wrapper(Lookup_BroadCast)
val Call_Sub_Pgm = udf(wrapper.foo(_: String, _: String))
```

Comment: thanks pasha for the approach. Code is working now but it's executing very slow.

sub_pgm.scala  has class wrapper code

main_pgm.scala has the udf code

both codes are in same package.

Comment: guess, slowness is other issue, related to implementation.

Comment: Yes. Found the issue. Thnx for help